# Counting Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider the following equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 20$$

> a) Count the number of integer solutions of the equation under the condition that $x_i \ge 0$ for $i=1, 2,\ldots 6$.

I found the answer, it is $53130$.

> b) Suppose that we choose one the solutions from part (a) at random. What is the probability that this solution will satisfy the condition that 
>   $0 \le x_i \le 8$ for $i = 1, 2,\ldots 6$. (Hint: Define $A_i$ the event that $x_i > 8$)

Comment: Can you expand on what you've done so far, or what you're having problem with?

Comment: for part a) I did ( n + r - 1)C(r - 1). I got 25C5. For part b) i don't know where to start. If I let Ai be the event that xi > 8, I don't understand how i would find the probability for the condition given.

Comment: $A_i$ is the complement of the probability you're trying to derive.

Comment: Ok, but i don't seem to understand how I would go about this problem. Am i still working with combinations here?

Comment: $P(0\le x_i\le 8)=1-P(x_i>8)=1-A_i$. And you can find $A_i$ in a similar fashion as in question a).

Comment: Okay thank you! I think i understand the problem now. Can you please let me know if I solved Ai correctly. I did (20 + 6 - 1)C(20)

Comment: If I use this as my Ai, I get a value of 6188. I can't subtract one from this. It does not make sense

Comment: $A_i$ is a probability, i.e. a ratio of all the favorable cases over all the possible cases.

Comment: I don't see an easy way of using the hint, as you may have two values greater than $8$, but I suspect the answer may be $\frac{27237}{53130}$ which you can simplify slightly

Answer (score 2):

Consider we have an arrangement of 20 balls and 5 dividers - representing six variables to contain 20 integer solutions.

How many ways are there to place the dividers between the balls, when more than one divider can be placed between any two balls ?  This is the permutation of 25 items composed of a group of 20 and a group of 5 indistinguishable items.

$$\lvert \Omega\rvert = {^{25}\mathsf C_{5}}$$

---

For part (b), the favoured event is: $A= \bigcap_{i=1}^6 \{0\leq x_i\leq 8\}$

Then its complement is: $A^\complement = \bigcup_{i=1}^6\{x>8\}$

That is, the complement is the event that at least one partition at least **9** balls.   To count this we first remove **9** balls and count the ways to arrange partitions between the rest.   Then multiply the result by the count of ways to select one of six numbers to add back the removed block of balls.   **However** we have over counted so must use the *Principle of Inclusion Exclusion* to account for cases where two partitions each have at least **9** .

$$\lvert A^\complement\rvert = {^6\mathsf C_1}\cdot{^{(20+5-9)}\mathsf C_5} -{^6\mathsf C_2}\cdot{^{(20+5-18)}\mathsf C_5}$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: If i remove 8 from 20, then the ways to arrange the partitions is 17C5. Is this correct? Then i multiply this value by (8+5)C5 ? After I divide this product by 25C5 I don't get a decimal value. Am i missing something?

Comment: No, @user234942 , you choose which of the 6 variables to add back unto.  That is $^6\mathsf C_k$.

Comment: Would it be 6C5?

Comment: Would i continue up to 6C6?

Comment: @user234942 You have only 20 balls; you can not reserve more than 2 lots of nine.